# Could not load library"/usr/local/lib/postgresql/rtpostgis-2.4.so"

Tags: python, postgis, gdal

When trying to deploy python project on mac following error ocurred.

```
 return self.cursor.execute(sql)
 psycopg2.InternalError: could not load library"/usr/local/lib/postgresql/rtpostgis-2.4.so":dlopen(/usr/local/lib/postgresql/rtpostgis-2.4.so, 10): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
 Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/postgresql/rtpostgis-2.4.so
 Reason: Incompatible library version: rtpostgis-2.4.so requires version 24.0.0 or later, but libgdal.20.dylib provides version 23.0.0
```

GDAL version is 2.2.4. It installed with no errors.

Comment: Did you solve this?